# Bootstrap dropdown inside a table doesn't work with .table-responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the link to the live example.
http://www.codeply.com/go/uBnL1bBs6v

From which you can see, the dropdown gets cutoff when I apply a layer `<div calss="table-responsive"></div>`to wrap the table.

If you remove the wrapper `<div class="table-responsive"></div>`, the dropdown works fine.

I was wondering what would be the problem and how do I fix it?
I added table-responsive class because I need the function to scroll between columns since I have a lot columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use this css code

```
.table-responsive>table .dropdown{position:static;}
.table-responsive>table .dropdown>.dropdown-menu{left:auto !important;top:auto !important;}
```

Answer (score 3):

The dropdown is hiding under the tr. You got to set this `position:relative` to the dropdown, that is the ul element. I have added this CSS rule to your codeply. **[Working Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/4qkaKAR60d)**

```
table.table ul.dropdown-menu{
    position:relative;
    float:none;
    max-width:160px;
}
```

Add this in the CSS rule and you see its fixed.

**Note:** in your demo the body height is very small so the drop down might still be seen as hidden. Give some height to your body (for demo).

Add this

```
body{
    height:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `table-responsive` class is creating a conflict with the class `table`. I will research better ways to solve it, but for the moment you can simply apply `height: 200px` to `table` to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just add to the `table-responsive` class `overflow: visible`

Comment: Well. This fixed the problem of the dropdown but the horizontal scroll bar of the responsive table doesn't work anymore